# Filtering overlapped rows in data frame based on majority count of labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How to filter duplicated rows with overlapped labels? I need a subset of `Dataframe` where duplicated rows are replaced with one row for which label count is max.

Consider a dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'X' : [1, -1, 1, 1, 3, -2, -1, -1],
 'Y' : [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, -1, 3, 3],
 'label' : [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2]
})
```

After filtering, the following subset `df_output` is expected

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({
 'X' : [1, -1, 3, -2], 
 'Y' : [2, 3, 2, -1],
 'label' : [0, 2, 2, 1]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for groupby mode i.e

```
df.groupby(['X','Y'])['label'].apply(lambda x : x.mode().values[0]).reset_index()
```

Output :

```
  X  Y  label
0 -2 -1      1
1 -1  3      2
2  1  2      0
3  3  2      2
```

Comment: Ohk you need mode I think. Hope my solution helps. Its better we clear this comment section,

Comment: Do vote when you get enough reputation. You can delete the comments now na. They are really lengthy